# How to identify last element in a Flow loop?

Tags: visual-workflow

In Flow, is there a built in way to know that I am working with the last element in a loop?  I can look at the collection size and keep a counter myself, but it would be useful if that info were available somewhere.

Sometimes you need to do something different with the last (or first) element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no inherent way to tell if you're on the first/last element. You would need to keep track of this yourself.